# almost upper bound

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ and $b\in \mathbb R$. We say that b is an **almost upper bound** of A if there is a finite number ( zero included) of $x\in A$ such that $x>b$. Let $C$ be the set of all $b\in \mathbb R$, such that b is an almost upper bound of A. $L=\inf\,C$ is said to be the upper limit of A, and denoted by $L=\lim\, \sup A$.

i) $L\in C$?

ii) How can I prove that $\lim\,\sup\,A\le \sup\,A$?

iii) How can I prove that if $\lim\,\sup\,A<\sup\,A$, then A has a greatest element?

Comment: If $A$ is finite, $C=\mathbb{R}$ and $L\notin C$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: ii) $\sup A$ is an almost upper bound of $A$.

iii) It should mean there exists a real number $b$ such that there is a finite non zero number of $x\in A$ with $x>b$.